# Get all the rows which are not have leading zero

Tags: sql

I need to `SELECT` all rows where `column1` does not have a leading `0`. `column1` has a `String` data type.

```
column1

0123455677
0987654321
2345567887
0233445566
3422245666
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: and what dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh  data type is string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ANSI SQL answer:

```
select * from tablename
where substring(column1 from 1 for 1) <> '0'
```

Some dbms products have `SUBSTR(column1, 1, 1)` instead, or `LEFT(column1, 1)`.

Comment: OP, note that it is poor practice to `SELECT *` - you should `SELECT` only the columns you wish to display. (The poster of this answer does not know which columns you have so quite correctly defaulted to `SELECT *`)

Answer (score 0):

I asume you are talking about a character field, as a numeric field wouldn't be displayed with leading 0's unless you format it ... anyway

for a character field you would select ...

```
WHERE column1 NOT LIKE '0%'
```

in case of a numeric field you might select ...

```
WHERE column1 >= 1000000000
```

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers. Single quotes for string literals.

Comment: here is leading zero so the field would be in varchar not numeric

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achive this. Here are three examples working for the oracle dbms(i don´t know your dbms).

```
-- using substr
select * from
(select '0123' t from dual union 
 select '123' t from dual union 
 select '5123' t from dual union 
 select '413123' t from dual union 
 select '0454' t from dual) tab
 where substr(tab.t,0,1) != 0;
-- using regex
 select * from
(select '0123' t from dual union 
 select '123' t from dual union 
 select '5123' t from dual union 
 select '413123' t from dual union 
 select '0454' t from dual) tab
 where regexp_like(tab.t,'^[^0]');
-- using the like operator
 select * from
(select '0123' t from dual union 
 select '123' t from dual union 
 select '5123' t from dual union 
 select '413123' t from dual union 
 select '0454' t from dual) tab
 where tab.t not like '0%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered, but you can also try

```
SELECT LEFT(column1, 1) AS firstLetter
FROM <table>
WHERE colum1 => 1
```

It works perfectly with strings.

Answer (score -1):

Well you need to check if first character is zero or not. Use `SUBSTR`.

```
SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE SUBSTR(COLUMN,1,1) <> '0';
```

Comment: I think that you are not right. We don't know what rdbms there is using. So, your answer is not correct because for exemple MSSQL Server does not have function `SUBSTR`